# Xcode error saying "cannot find type 'TestModelCoreData' in scope when using core data fetch request, yet it compiles and runs

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, xcode12

The code below is my view that I am messing around with core data in but it keeps giving me the error that it cannot find the entity in the scope, yet the application runs fine and everything gets saved and fetched just fine.

[Here are screenshots of the errors it gives](https://imgur.com/a/xYyGrKs)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: TestModelCoreData.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TestModelCoreData.name, ascending: false)
        ]
    ) var entities: FetchedResults<TestModelCoreData>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!").padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                let newEntry = TestModelCoreData(context: self.moc)
                newEntry.name = "New name"
                
                if self.moc.hasChanges {
                    try? self.moc.save()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Add entry")
            }
            
            List(entities, id: \.self) { entity in
                Text(entity.name ?? "Unknown")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Can you check if 'MyModel.xcdatamodel' is actually added to the project(i.e. check for target membership)?

Comment: @Prafulla [here](https://imgur.com/a/npCBr61) is a screenshot of the target membership for the data model.

Comment: No issue in code as everything is running file, Try to delete derived data etc. you can try following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60861247/9838937

Comment: Yes I had the exact same problem today with Xcode 12.3 I just closed Xcode completely and then restarted it and everything built fine. Even with the error I was able to do a build though could not run the project on the simulator. So if you ever get an error that you cannot find the Entity in scope try restarting Xcode.

Comment: Is it works on Simulator? Or you just have this error on canvas preview? If yes maybe you just have to mock your entity in preview. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66241773/15224199

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just reopened Xcode .

[SwiftUI 2.0 CoreData issues with new project - 'Cannot find type 'Item' in scope'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603754/swiftui-2-0-coredata-issues-with-new-project-cannot-find-type-item-in-scope)

Comment: omg so upsetting

Comment: Amazing how this is the fix.

Answer (score 16):

This issue persists as of Xcode 12.2. It is not unique to CoreData. It can be triggered by e.g. creating an extension, then moving that extension to a separate file. **If your code builds and runs** despite a Swift compiler error "Cannot find 'xyz' in scope", try just closing and reopening your project before clearing caches, deleting derived data, etc.

Comment: This solved my error

Comment: This bad boy just keeps on persisting, still around as of 15.0!

Answer (score 2):

If none of the solutions provided seems to work ( restarting Xcode, recreating the project, checking if has been added to Target Membership, deleting Derived Data, etc, ... ) and despite the IDE warnings try to build the project anyway with `cmd` + `B` . This resolved the issue on my end.