# How to move files in Xcode without causing "Cannot find 'FileName' in Scope"?

Tags: xcode

I want to make my project more organized, so I created new groups and dragged files into those groups. I am doing all of this in Xcode, not finder or terminal. However, now, Xcode shows "Cannot find 'FileName' in Scope" errors next to references to classes in those files.

How do I solve this problem?

I tried building the project and cleaning the build folder.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue today with Xcode 12.2 and an iOS 14.2 project. I created a file for a new struct, wrote some code in ViewController that created instances of the struct, and then for housecleaning I moved the struct's .swift file. At that point I saw the error "Cannot find [type] in scope."

Product | Clean Build Folder didn't do the trick.

**Closing and reopening Xcode worked for me.**

I'm not sure if the initial clean helped or not.

There are more detailed answers here, and your particular case may be covered:
[SwiftUI 2.0 CoreData issues with new project - 'Cannot find type 'Item' in scope'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603754/swiftui-2-0-coredata-issues-with-new-project-cannot-find-type-item-in-scope)

Comment: How does this bug make it to production, and persist even in .3 build?...

Comment: Would that I knew. Visual Studio has its issues, too, but I don't have enough experience in XCode to know what to expect.

Comment: Same Xcode issues, another decade. Sigh... Honestly Apple software has mostly been coasting downhill since the former CEO passed away...still no CEO at Apple yet.

Comment: That is an example of why tech companies need engineers (at least hobbyist engineers) as CEO. Former CEO was at least a hobbyist engineer and obviously his co-founder was an engineer. Sad that I spent so much of the past calendar decade using Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue today using Xcode 12.3 (12C33):

---

**Solution**

1. Removed the impacted files from Xcode (without trashing them)
2. Tried adding the files back with the create folder references option selected
3. Found that this action generated **Cannot find 'type' in scope** error
4. Resolved the error by removing the files references and select the create groups option when copying the files back into the project.

*BTW - I found these methods work while using either the Add Files option or dragging the files/folders into the project.*

Answer (score 0):

I found some "hack" to fix it.

Lets say you wanna move folder `Models` to your project. Open AppCode and create `Model` group using IDE tools. Then open XCode, select `Model` folder and perform `Add files to "Model"` action. It worked out in my case.

From my understanding, the problem is with forlders, not with files.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers work for you (Clean build folder and restart Xcode) then delete the derived data in `DerivedData/{Project Name}_some_hash`

You can find that folder quickly by going to Settings in Xcode. There is a link to it if you go to Derived Data under the Xcode menu at top → Settings → Locations.